How to use different version of telegram-web-app.js
I am trying to use a feature of telegram-web-app.js, which is available in version 7.7.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#initializing-mini-apps
When adding the script in my app, I get version 7.4/7.6. The version of the script is set by the URL hash which Telegram adds to our app's URL, when opening it in its context. And it explicitly adds tgWebAppVersion=7.4 for web Telegram and 7.6 for Telegram App (both Windows and iOS).
Does somebody know how to raise this number? I asked Google and ChatGPT with no luck so far.
Thanks!

Do you have any update on it?

Still not. But as far as I understand so far, it is related to the App Stores' versions of the Telegram app. The bot app version is from 07/07/2024, so I hope it will be updated soon in the TG app. The previous one (7.6) is from 01.07.2024.

for me script is still showing var webAppVersion = '6.0';
https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js

@ErShakirAnsari, for sure it is hardcoded in the JS source code. However, the version which is used in the logic is taken by the #tgWebAppData=.....tgWebAppVersion=7.6 URL hash, added by the Telegram app. As stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78453108/why-telegram-web-app-api-version-is-6-0-and-cant-be-changed-while-to-access-fe?rq=2

Finally, it appeared that the next version of the Telegram app started using the newest version (7.8). So I could conclude that we have no control over it.

Can you elaborate what you did though? Did you just wait?

I actually now understand how this is handled. The installed Telegram app on the phone is what defines the Mini App version. Therefore you must check whether the feature is supported for the currently installed version for each user such as:
useEffect(() => {
    if (swipeBehavior.supports('disableVerticalSwipe')) {
      swipeBehavior.disableVerticalSwipe();
    }
  }, [swipeBehavior]);


@s.khetcho, fortunately it is not necessary to check. The TG script makes this check for us and only logs a warning if the feature is not supported. No need to worry about that.
And the good news - the feature works <3

you may need download the js file, then replace the 7.7 limitation in source code. Load this file from you project assets folder or OSS, then you got the ability of 7.7.

If we do so, we will lie the script that the app supports the features for the higher versions but not actually use the feature, I guess. Did not test.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
